# How to use efficiently use GAE datastore for iOS/Android turn based game

Tags: google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

I have decided to use the google app engine for my game. I am going to use the python datastore to store information.

I need to store information about each user and the games being played. For each user I need to store name, id, games won etc. For each game i need to store player1 id, player 2 id and a few other game related strings.

What is the best way to link game info with users? Should I have a game1, game2, game3 property in the user database, or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Not really. You've got it right.

Comment: Is that the most efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a "repeated" property in the datastore, which provides a list of values. In your case, you might do something like this:

```
class Game(ndb.Model);
    ...

class User(ndb.Model):
    games = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Game, repeated=True)
```

In your code, myUser.games would be a list of keys to for game objects.

Alternatively, if your games have a fixed number of players, you could make the relationship in the other direction:

```
class Game(ndb.Model):
    player1 = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Player)
    player2 = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Player)
```

And then to get all games for a player, you'd query something like `Game.query(player1=myPlayer.key)` (and again for player2).

Comment: There are two players to every game. The second option looks great!

Comment: The 1st option is better from design point of view. And would be cheaper to host (execute queries).

Comment: Yes, except the first option makes it hard to tell which player that user is (player 1 or player 2) and you'd still need queries to get the users for a particular game.

Comment: What option do you think is better? Now that I look at it again they seem fairly similar.

Comment: They are pretty similar. If you're sure about the two-player-per-game and you want to be able to distinguish P1 from P2, I would suggest the second option, since with the first option you'll need some other way to identify which player is which.